# Return to the previous section after clicking to another page without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js libary,
How can I Return to the previous section  after clicking to another page without scrolling?
I tried to find an answer on fullpage.js GITHUB page

Answer (score 1):

> [moveTo(section, slide) scrolls the page to the given section and slide. The first slide, the visible one by default, will have index 0.](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#methods)

or `silentMoveTo` if that fits you better.

Comment: Exactly the way to go for it! :)

Comment: Thank you, But I want to  Return to the previous section after continue to other page in my site not other section

Comment: Then use `moveSectionUp()` or `moveSlideLeft()`, depending on if you have a vertical or horizontal layout. It's really all documented.